# CentOS 7 Kernel 3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64 server crashing at random time

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, vmware, crash

I have a CentOS 7 server running in a VMware environment. Recently I have upgraded to kernel 3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64; since then, I am noticing servers crashing at random times. Is there an known issue with this version of the kernel?

Comment: Reading the output of `journalctl -k -b-1` would prove helpful in understanding why the server crashed. If there's anything interesting there that you don't understand, I suggest adding it to the question.

Comment: upgraded to new kernel `3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64`. It didn't crash last 24 hours. let me monitor some more time.